# SFTP on Windows Server 2016, Error: Got eof from child process

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla

I get "**Got eof from child process**" when attempting to connect to SFTP on Windows Server 2016 using FileZilla. The debug trace is below. Does anyone know why? And the remedy?

Notes:

1. OpenSSH is running on the server
2. I can open an SSH session with the username and password with PuTTY
3. I can navigate to folders with PuTTY (cd, dir, etc)
4. TLS1.x is disabled for other security reasons so I cannot use "explicit FTP Over TLS"
5. "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" in the log below is my IP edited for security reasons

FileZilla Debug Log:

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 0
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Trace:  Going to execute C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\fzsftp.exe
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=11
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    open "myusername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 22
Trace:  Looking up host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" for SSH connection
Trace:  Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
Trace:  We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.60.2
Trace:  Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Trace:  Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9
Trace:  Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:  Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256 (SHA-NI accelerated)
Trace:  Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/rsa-sha2-512/rsa-sha2-256 host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:  Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:  ssh-ed25519 255 SHA256:+N7KuNqe4nd0Qq6EvuEDFsWX+EeLIkDN0SebsjsPITQ
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 GCM outbound encryption
Trace:  Initialised AES256 GCM outbound MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 GCM inbound encryption
Trace:  Initialised AES256 GCM inbound MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Status: Using username "myusername". 
Trace:  Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Trace:  Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
Command:    Pass: *************
Trace:  Sent password
Trace:  Access granted
Trace:  Opening main session channel
Trace:  Opened main channel
Trace:  Started a shell/command
Status: Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Trace:  Got eof from child process
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(64)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Reset(66) in state 3
Error:  Could not connect to server
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Status: Waiting to retry...
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 0
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Trace:  Going to execute C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\fzsftp.exe
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=11
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    open "myusername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 22
Trace:  Looking up host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" for SSH connection
Trace:  Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
Trace:  We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.60.2
Trace:  Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Trace:  Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9
Trace:  Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:  Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256 (SHA-NI accelerated)
Trace:  Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/rsa-sha2-512/rsa-sha2-256 host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:  Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:  ssh-ed25519 255 SHA256:+N7KuNqe4nd0Qq6EvuEDFsWX+EeLIkDN0SebsjsPITQ
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 GCM outbound encryption
Trace:  Initialised AES256 GCM outbound MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 GCM inbound encryption
Trace:  Initialised AES256 GCM inbound MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Status: Using username "myusername". 
Trace:  Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Trace:  Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
Command:    Pass: *************
Trace:  Sent password
Trace:  Access granted
Trace:  Opening main session channel
Trace:  Opened main channel
Trace:  Started a shell/command
Status: Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Trace:  Got eof from child process
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(64)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Reset(66) in state 3
Error:  Could not connect to server
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
```

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I got "same" problem when connecting to the Linux machine.

**Error messages**

- Trace:    **Got eof from child process**
- Trace:    **CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)**
- Trace:    **CSftpConnectOpData::Reset(66) in state 3**

Filezilla with zero debug ouptput says:

```
Status: Connecting to server.net...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=11
...
Status: Connected to server.net
Error:  Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP on server: could not connect
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Turn on the debug mode in menu `FileZilla > Edit > Settings > Debug > Debug information in message log: 3-verbose`

```
Status: Connecting to server.net...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=11
...
Status: Connected to server.net
Error:  Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP on server: could not connect
Error:  Could not connect to serverError:   Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP on server: could not connect
Trace:  Got eof from child process
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Reset(66) in state 3
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

**Root cause** 
The **Welcome message** send from the server **was too long** for `SFTP` protocol!

**Solution** 
In my case I have recently created the message to be shown after login and since the SFTP stops working. 
So the fix was pretty easy: login to the remote server using `ssh` and clear unnecessary output generated by my `~/.bashrc` file where I recently setup custom welcome message to appear after new shell is opened.

**Kudos** 
Kudos goes to help page of [WinSCP Received too large (… B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 102400 B](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_large_packet)!

Comment: The problem is the mere presence of badly implemented welcome message, not its length.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, it is possible - I just used to the .bashrc to `cat ~/readme` with my notes with working instruction related to that server. After I disabled that cat output then the FileZilla connected again without any problems using SFTP. Meanwhile I tested connection with WinSCP that warned me about `Received too large (xxx B) SFTP packet.`  including the beginning of the readme file.. Kudos! The readme contains "just" couple of lines.
There might be someone else so silly to do same. This is to warn/help them ;)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the "sftp-server.exe" program in sshd_config was not in the path, so it could not be run.

Fix:

1. Navigate to: C:\ProgramData\
2. Open "sshd_config" in Notepad
3. Find the "Subsystem" setting
4. Set the full path to be specific to: "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64\sftp-server.exe"
5. Save the file
6. Run services.msc
7. Find "OpenSSH SSH Server"
8. Right-click and restart

**# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64\sftp-server.exe"**